# C: Multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, macos

Is multithreading supported in C? If yes, then how do I try? Is there any open source library that lets me do it and is the library supported on Mac OS X?

I haven't found any article saying that it's supported.

Comment: try POSIX pthreads..
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread.h.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C is not intrinsically a multithreaded language; however there are many libraries which add threading functionality.

- `pthreads` is a library compatible with any POSIX system, so it is supported on OSX. I found https://hpc-tutorials.llnl.gov/posix/ to be a good place to start.
- Win32 has a threading library for C described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/multithreading-with-c-and-win32.
- `Glib` adds threading supported, and has the advantage of being completely cross-platform, as long as glib is installed on the target machine. There is some information here: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Threads.html

Comment: I meant that the language can be used for threading. I'll clarify.

Comment: BTW there is a win32 version of pthreads [here](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)

Answer (score 2):

C has no concept whatever of threads. There is no thread support in C Standard. There are extensions available that can implement multi threading - one of which is pthreads.

Be aware because C language has no natural support of threads you as the programmer have to take care of everything and you will not be protected against any of the pitfalls of multi-threaded programming.

Comment: Oh and be careful - a bunch of C functions are known not to be thread safe (ie localtime and more) OS's often provide thread safe versions like localtime_r

Comment: What does the _r part stand for? like, _t is for typedef'd.

Comment: It stands for Reentrant, duh.

Answer (score 2):

the new dialect - C1X, will offer multi-threading out of the box, as stated from wikipedia:

> Multithreading support (_Thread_local storage-class specifier,  header including thread creation/management functions, mutex, condition variable and thread-specific storage functionality, as well as the _Atomic type qualifier and  for uninterruptible object access).

currently of courae as mentioned above, multi-threading is not supported in the newest dialect of c - C99

Answer (score 1):

Pthreads.  OSX has posix support.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the majority of multithreaded programming on Mac OS X is done in Objective-C or C++, not plain C.  (I realize that this isn't exactly an answer to the question that you asked, but you might want to know about alternatives.)  In Objective-C, you'd use NSThread or, in Snow Leopard and later, Grand Central Dispatch (GCD).  In C++, you could use the threads library from boost.org, which has the advantage of being cross-platform.