# C signals vs. eventhandler

Tags: c, events, signals

i am interested in the C programming, lately. I like how you only have a 'minimal' set of functions and datatypes (the C standard library) and still you can create almost everything with it.

But now to my question:
How do you make simple event-handling in C? I have read about the signals.h header and this would be what i am looking for... if there were signals exclusivly reserved for the user. But i can never be sure that the environment unexpectedly raises one of the signals that i can use with the C standard library.
Okay... there is the extended signals header in linux/unix with 2(?) signals for the user... but i can imagine situations where you need more... 
Besides i want to learn writing C platform independent. I heard about "emulating signals" by listening to a socket... but that would also not be platform independent.

Is there any way to write a C program that has to handle events without getting platform dependent only by help of the standard C library?

Thank you for any hints;

Comment: "*listening to a socket... but that would also not be platform independent.*" In terms of what please? Basic socket functions are supported by all mayor platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you are going to run into platform dependencies here. You can write a multithreaded application, where one thread waits for some input and then sends a message / makes a call when that input has arrived (such as waiting for an input string on a console). But that is not baked into C99, and you would have to rely on platform dependent third party libraries. Here is a useful post on that subject. I know this isn't the answer you want, but I hope it helps.

[C: Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774778/c-multithreading)

edit: C11 supports multithreading natively, see 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header

I haven't used this yet.

Comment: Well, that helps me a lot, since I can certainly stick to C11 as I am new to C. I think I was just looking for simple multithreading. The signals seem to be just simple jumps in a sequentially way. Instead I should be able to just call the functions i would haven given to the signal. This should have the same effect. Thank you for bringing light into this.

Comment: Consider a program that needs to handle input from the user and also do some backend processing of some other sort. You would have one thread that continually polls for console input some the user, and also continually polls your backend process for outputs to present to the user. It would simply exchange data. If you were using Java, .NET, or anything else with a GUI front end and event handlers, you'd probably still want to follow a multithreaded approach if your program is doing several things concurrently. Otherwise the UI will hang periodically while the program is busy.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, that is exactly what Unix designed for, 2 user signals. Supposedly it all depends on what you use signal for. If you are just to relaying some events asynchronously, use sockets will do. Look up for event-loop. You can even create unlimited complexity behind that. Signals are a very special group of functions for OS specific reasons, such as somebody is trying to kill you. In that respect, the options should be limited in order to trim down overhead for OS operations.

My suggestion is to stay away from signals, unless you know very specifically what you are using it for. Signal is used for OS to communicate with you, not for you to communicate with yourself, although from many different places. And there are only defined reasons why OS want to give you a call. Hence, I tend to think the original 2 user defined signals are more than enough.