# Threading and Thread Safety in C

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, atomic, c99

When there is a common set of global data that needs to be shared among several threaded processes, I typically have used a thread token to protect the shared resource:

[image]

***Edit - 7/22/15*** (to incorporate ***[atomics](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/07/c11-concurrency-tutorial-part-4-atomic-type.html)*** as a viable option, per Jens comments)

***My [First] question is***, in C, if I write my routines in such a way as to guarantee each thread accesses one, and only one element of an array:

[image]

Is there any reason to think that asynchronous and simultaneous access to *different indices* of the same *unprotected* array (as shown in diagram) would be a problem?

***Second question:*** Given that *an object that can be accessed as
an atomic entity, even in the presence of asynchronous interrupts* ( ***[C99 - 7.14 Signal handling](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)***  ) would using ***[atomics](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic)*** be an effective method for thread protection for an otherwise unprotected variable?

[image]

***Edit*** (Clarifications to address questions in comments to this point):
- Specifics for this application:
- Target OS: Windows 7/8/10
- Compiler : C99 compliant (cannot use C11, which include the _[*Atomic() type specifier*](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/07/c11-concurrency-tutorial-part-4-atomic-type.html)  )
- H/W : Intel i7 family

Comment: Of course, unless the elements are pointers to some shared address  that all (or some of) your threads will try to write to. As a matter of fact, your threads can even safely access the whole array as long as all the accesses will be read-only. If one or more of your threads are writers, you need synchronization.

Comment: @PSkocik - my threads will need to read as well as write to these locations.  I am investigating ways to do this without using protection or synchronization (beyond assigning a very specific index to each thread).

Comment: Since C does not talk about threads at all this is left unspecified. In practice it's a different story.

Comment: @usr- then you would agree with quagrana's response?  If so, can you expand a little?

Comment: @ryyker For the question you asked the answer is "none". If you have different scenario in mind then you need to update question or ask a new one with specifics of how you want to share the array between threads, possible number of threads and any other relevant information.

Comment: @ryyker There is no way to avoid read and write barriers and synchronization.  Even if one thread does all the work, sets a flag, and another thread reads the result after it sees the flag, you still have to use synchronization primitives.

Comment: @usr C (C11) does talk about threads and there's a standard header and a set of library functions.

Comment: @BlueMoon - None?  That is what I was thinking, until I read quamrana's answer.  Now I am not sure...  In reality, my scenario is that I have an array of 16 ints, that for reason's of thread locking (the potential for) I do not want to constrain this variable from being access simultaneously by multiple (16) threads. I am investigating how to do it without protecting the array.

Comment: @ryyker I don't know much more about this. Also, see BlueMoon's comment. Note, that all realistic hardware architectures are fully memory coherent all the time. It is impossible to program against a machine where writing to x can cause y in an unrelated thread to be garbled. Real compilers make strong guarantees here because of that.

Comment: @usr - Thanks.  Just to be clear, you seem to be offering a position differing from the idea quamrana has stated, i.e. that _I can have confidence_ that if I constrain each thread to access one (and only one) element of the array, I should be okay?

Comment: @ryyker depends on the compiler. It is free to write to more bytes than you intended to. I'd be confident for MSVC but I can't say anything about the others. Bitfields come to mind as an exception.

Comment: @usr - This is a Windows app, although not MSVC, I am using a compiler that is very ANSI C compliant, and `type` sizes are very well defined.  Would like to read more of your thoughts though on compiler dependency with respect to this topic.  Any good links you can share?

Comment: Your idea for the first picture is a bit misleading. There is a third way for shared thread access, atomics. The last C standard, C11, provides interfaces for that.

Comment: @JensGustedt - _misleading_:   I assume you mean I did not include atomics?  Are atomics also part of C99?  I am constrained to use ANSI C only.

Comment: @ryyker, I suppose by ANSI C you mean C89? ANSI has adopted all subsequent ISO standards. For atomics, no they came with C11, to use these, you'd have to modernize a bit.

Comment: @JensGustedt - C99.  Still archaic by C11 comparison  I suppose.  And I am constrained to use C99 for projects related to this OP.

Comment: @JensGustedt - It appears atomics _are_ defined in C99.  Refer to ***[7.14 Signal handling <signal.h>](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)***.  (just ran a test to declare one in my compiler - works!)  I still do not fully understand them, or how (or even if they need to) apply to this particular problem.  I will enjoy reading and experimenting though.  Thanks again for bringing them into the conversation.

Comment: @ryyker, `sig_atomic_t` is another kind of "atomic" it has nothing to do with multithreading. It only guarantees integrity of data between the "normal" code and a signal handler. Don't use it for threads.

Comment: @JensGustedt - that explains why it has been difficult to make the connections in my mind of how I would apply this.  Can you please link me something relating to the kind of _atomic_ you were referring to in your previous comments?.

Comment: @ryyker, surprisingly the wikpedia article is called "Linearizability" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (which looks like a C standard of some sort)
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf sayeth:

> NOTE 1 Two threads of execution can update and access separate memory
>   locations without interfering with each other
>
> NOTE 13 Compiler transformations that introduce assignments to a
>   potentially shared memory location that would not be modified by the
>   abstract machine are generally precluded by this standard, since such
>   an assignment might overwrite another assignment by a different thread
>   in cases in which an abstract machine execution would not have
>   encountered a data race. This includes implementations of data member
>   assignment that overwrite adjacent members in separate memory
>   locations. We also generally preclude reordering of atomic loads in
>   cases in which the atomics in question may alias, since this may
>   violate the "visible sequence" rules.

The way I understand it, this would preclude quamrana's concerns and guarantee you that unprotected writes to separate memory locations should never result in undefined behavior if there is no data race.

Comment: Nice link and notes for open compilers.  Suggests perhaps similar statements (even remotely) may be made in any of the ANSI standards versions?

Comment: @ninjalj - although the date shown in the link says _April 12, 2011_, the title indicates _ISO/IEC 9899_, which is clearly C99.  But its all academic as I could not find any part of the first NOTE in the text of the pdf the link points to.

Comment: @ryyker: It's actually ISO/IEC 9899:2011. C99 says nothing about threads, C11 does. Note 1 is from the definition of memory location at 3.14. Note 13 is from 5.1.2.4.

Answer (score 2):

In C it will depend on your platform, that is your combination of compiler, processor architecture and operating system.

Your compiler can choose how to use the internal registers and instructions of the cpu to make the executable seem to perform the intent of the program. And C may know nothing about threads. It is usually the job of the operating system to provide a threading library.

There may be processors which might perform the write to an element of your array by reading a much larger patch of memory than just one element, then overwrite just the right bits that forms one element within internal registers and then writing the whole patch back. A single threaded program would work just fine, but two or more threads which interrupt each other could cause chaos in the array.

On the other hand it may work out just fine.

And as has been said, read-only access is always just fine.

Also, google is your friend. It found this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774778/c-multithreading).

Comment: _depend on your platform_,  I did not expect there would be a platform dependency element to this problem, i.e. though it would be constrained purely to C standard implementations.  (Your answer has been voted up, so someone else agrees..., can you (or the up-voter) say more on this? )

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Both C11 and pthreads allow reads/writes to different memory locations without any problem (as in the example of OP). While processor can read in more into memory, it doesn't introduce any uncertainties as you state. Simply a write by another thread at one location will invalidate the cache line and thus it has to re-read before next read or write (exact mechanism depends on the cache coherency protocol). At worst, this could be bad for performance due to frequent invalidation. But there's no "correctness" issue or any "may or may not work" guesses.

Comment: @BlueMoon - Practically speaking _bad for performance_ will not be an issue for this application (i.e. it is a windows application monitoring physiological events, nothing fast or burdensome).  But what do you mean about  _But there's "correctness" issue_ ?

Comment: @BlueMoon - just read the edit to your comment, got it.  Thanks.

Comment: @BlueMoon I know nothing about C11, but I had thought that C did not define memory writes. I had thought that the issue of packing could be to do with alignment and writing to memory without overwriting adjacent variables.

Comment: ***Note***:  C11 is not part of this question .  I cannot use C11 (although that would evidently change the possibilities), I am constrained to using C99 version of ANSI C.  @BlueMoon - does this change your stated thoughts? (comment above).

Comment: @ryyker No. None of the implementations I am familiar with (pthreads, Solaris threads, C11, Boost) cause any problem. I haven't heard of any other implementation that behaves differently.

Comment: @ryyker: An example of a CPU where this is a problem is a DSP that can only access 16 bits, and your code wants to write a single byte. The DSP has to load 16 bits, change 8, and write back 16 bits. However, this kind of CPU is not likely to have a thread implementation to worry about.

Comment: @ZanLynx - Even if threads _were_ implemented, the persuasive arguments in the comments here (Blue Moon's in particular) suggest that this would still not be a problem.  i.e. the compiler implementation accommodates this scenario.  See comment regarding cache coherency protocol above.  (which I am not yet familiar with, but am looking at).

Comment: @ryyker: I don't see anything in Blue Moon's comments that address hardware limitations. He just says that "I haven't heard of any ... that behaves differently." Neither have I. Because on hardware that weird, you don't *do* threads.

Comment: @ZanLynx: besides DSPs, the first Alpha CPUs could only read/write whole words. AFAIK, that's the only (ancient) major CPU with such problems, and it got fixed in later Alpha CPUs....

Comment: ...  cf: http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/82final/5841/5841pro_017.html _an Alpha processor may allow atomic access only to an aligned longword or an aligned quadword. Reading or writing an aligned longword or quadword of memory is atomic with respect to any other thread of execution on the same processor or on other processors. Newer Alpha processors with the byte-word extension also provide atomic access to bytes and aligned words._

Answer (score 1):

If each thread is accessing a different array element, and only the element it is "assigned", this shouldn't be a problem.  Both scenarios above are essentially equivalent, since each array element has its own address.

Comment: Both scenarios are fundamentally different. The first describes access to an array (memory range) shared among 3 threads. The seconds describes access to 3 individual ints, where each thread accesses a different int.