# Creating a "interrupt safe" memory pool

Tags: c, synchronization, interrupt, atomic, memory-pool

I have written a simple memory pool which is thread-safe on multi-threaded systems (i.e. systems with an OS which handles thread scheduling). It uses some simple locking around each function, but it relies on the fact that another thread won't hold the lock forever. It uses a **linked list of blocks**, i.e. the head of the list always points to the next free block (and allocated blocks are not in the list).

But to make this work with interrupts, where I cannot risk locking inside the interrupt, the only thing I could think of was:

```
while (true)
{
    // iterate through the list of blocks and atomically acquire
    // a previously unacquired block

    for (int i = 0; i < pool->numberOfBlocks; i++)
    {
        // try to acquire this block atomically
        if (atomic_exchange(&pool->isBlockAcquired[i], 1) == 0)
             return pool->blocks[i];
    }
}
```

But this is far less performant than a linked list with locking, since it needs to iterate through the entire array. On the other hand, I don't want to have "one memory pool per interrupt" because I'd like to be able to allocate in one interrupt and free in a different one (if needed).

So I guess my question boils down to: how do I create a interrupt-safe linked list which I can use for a memory pool? Or (if I made an "XY problem") how do I create a simple lockless interrupt-safe memory pool, which can be shared among interrupts?

Comment: Sidenote: don't use compiler extension if there are standard ways. Use atomics, not the `__sync_...` builtins; they are obsolete.

Comment: Where you say "interrupt", do you mean signals / signal handlers?

Comment: @Olaf: thanks, yes that makes sense, but this is just the concept.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: well any timer, or hardware interrupt, or whatever might temporarily "interrupt" my code. But since they have different priority levels, if a higher level interrupt enters just after I acquired a lock in some user code, I cannot let interrupt "wait until the lock is released". My initial code ran on a multithreaded OS, so I just wrote a lock around linked-list operations, and this ensured the head always pointed to a valid block, while any other thread would shortly spin until the different thread finished acquiring a block (and released the lock).

Comment: Now I am programming the microcontroller directly, without an OS, so most synchronization patterns I got accustomed to won't work since there is no fair sharing of processing time between interrupts.

Comment: @Lou, your clarification that you are writing for a freestanding implementation is helpful, but also begs the question of exactly which implementation, for which hardware.

Comment: Furthermore, it seems like your reference to an implementation for a multi-threaded environment may have been a bit of a red herring.  Is your target microcontroller environment in fact multi-threaded?

Comment: @John: presuming that the code used `<stdatomics>`, does it matter which hardware it is? The loop above should work with interrupts *and* threads, if I am right. No, the environment is *not* multi-threaded. The code I linked to is an implementation which works for multi-threded systems, why the environment I am targetting *isn't* (a ARM cortex M4, without an OS). I'll remove the link to avoid confusion.

Comment: Could you use an array of struct?  Each element of the array, would be exclusively accessible to its own interrupt for writes, and any element can be read by any interrupt.  _[This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548355/threading-and-thread-safety-in-c)_ is centered more on a question about thread safety, but might have something for you to consider regarding safe storage of interrupt flags.

Comment: @ryyker: I would prefer to have a more generic solution so that I can allocate ("borrow") in one interrupt, and release ("return") in a different one, if possible. Well, it's likely all borrowing for a certain pool *will* be made from a single interrupt, and then potentially the block will be released from elsewhere, but I would like to see what would be a better approach than the loop I've posted above (which already does this without specific dependencies).

Comment: Do you not know the type/source of interrupts until run-time?

Comment: @Lou, if your freestanding C implementation in fact provides the facilities defined by `stdatomic.h` -- which freestanding implementations are not required to do -- and if you are committed to relying on those, then no, the hardware probably doesn't matter.  On the other hand, the question does seem to be too broad.  Have you consulted Google for information about "lock free linked lists"?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: honestly, I didn't google it, because I was concentrated on memory pool alone. I boiled it down to a "lock free linked list" while writing this question, so perhaps all I needed to do was write the question. Well, if it's too broad I'll try to google a bit. There are a couple of SO questions related to memory pools, but only with locking or per-interrupt pools. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ryyker: yes, they will be fixed, but I prefer writing (and then unit testing) as much portable codebase as possible to allow me to share it easily between projects. I can always do a "hand made" custom solution for a specific project, but then I end up with non-reusable code. And the code in the question already is *mostly* usable, but I don't like the `O(n)` complexity. If it's possible to create a lockless linked list on a microcontroller without multi-threading, then my problem is solved universally.

Comment: I get the impression that OP wants to avoid "priority inversion" (which is of course a good idea), but I am not sure. If OP confirms or nobody else contradicts I would recommend the concept of "priority ceiling protocol", which is one of the recipes against the problem and the one which is for example applied in the OSEK operating system. Your preferred search engine will provide information on other recipes.