# Producer Consumer using semaphores-c

Tags: c, synchronization, multiprocessing, semaphore, producer-consumer

Problem:

- All processes have an array of elements.
- Producer stores a value in his array.
- All consumers(n) must store this value on their array before a producer can produce additional element.
- All consumers should store the element and wait until the producer creates a new one.

So in my implementation I'm using three semaphores: all(as a barrier)=1, new=0 and a mutex=1. I'm also using a shared counter=0 to count how many consumers have read the element.

Code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "sys/sem.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"

int sem_id;
int shmid;
typedef struct sharedMemory{
    int value;
}sharedMemory;

union semun {
    int                 val;
    struct semid_ds *   buf;
    unsigned short *    array;
};

#define M 4
#define N 2

typedef enum semIndex{
    mutex= 0,
    all=1,
    new=2
}semIndex;


int sem_init(semIndex index,int val){
    union semun sem_union;
    sem_union.val = val;
    if (semctl(sem_id, index, SETVAL, sem_union) == -1) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int up(semIndex index) {
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = index;
    sem_b.sem_op = 1;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to up");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int down(semIndex index) {
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = index;
    sem_b.sem_op = -1;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to up");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void *getShMemory(int memory) {
    shmid = shmget((key_t)1234+memory, sizeof(sharedMemory), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmget failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void* shared_memory = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return shared_memory;
}

int main(void){
    srand(getpid() + rand()%500);
    int *array = malloc(M * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        array[i] = rand() % 20;
    }
    sem_id = semget(6846, 3, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    sharedMemory *sharedMem = (sharedMemory*) getShMemory(2);
    sem_init(all,1);
    sem_init(mutex,1);
    sem_init(new,0);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid>0){
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            down(all);
            down(mutex);
            sharedMem->value = array[i];
            up(mutex);
            up(new);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            printf("%d,",array[j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    else{
        sem_id = semget(6846, 3, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        int *array = malloc(M*sizeof(int));
        sharedMemory* consumerMem = (sharedMemory*)getShMemory(1);
        down(new);
        consumerMem->value = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
                if(fork() == 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
                        down(mutex);
                        consumerMem = (sharedMemory*)getShMemory(1);
                        sharedMemory *sharedMem = (sharedMemory*) getShMemory(2);
                        array[j] = sharedMem->value;
                        consumerMem->value++;
                        up(mutex);

                        if (consumerMem->value == N) {
                            down(mutex);
                            consumerMem->value = 0;
                            up(mutex);
                            up(all);            //signal producer to create new element
                        }
                        down(new);   //wait for new element
                        up(new);     //unblock one more consumer
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
                        printf("%d,",array[j]);
                    }
                    putchar('\n');
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Sometimes it works as intended so it ought to be a race condition but I can't pinpoint it.Any clues?

*Update:*
I managed to run debug with Clion. I can't replicate the problem with the debugger so it's even harder to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Unless this is an exercise to learn thread safety, there are easier ways.  For example, instead of having multiple copies of the array that need to be protected by semaphores , you could create an array of arrays, with `numProcess` elements as the first index.  (  eg array[numProcesses][M] ).  Then each process can write freely to its area of the array without conflict.  ( as explained _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548355/threading-and-thread-safety-in-c)_ )  See note 1 referenced in first answer of link.

Comment: As you said it is an exercise for thread safety. I can only share this structure(sharedMem) among processes along with shared semaphores.

Comment: It kinda looks like you're trying to use Sys V semaphores in the way one would use POSIX semaphores.  Sys V semaphores allow you to perform operations on an array of semaphores rather than having to operate on them one-by-one.  And it's an atomic operation, too.  Instead of trying to abstract out the Sys V semaphore operations to look like POSIX semaphore operations, consider implementing something more specific to your use-case like a read-write lock.

Comment: I can change that but i don't think it will solve my problem. I mean the semops are being treated correctly ( as far as I can see from printing messages at least)

Comment: Ok so I used POSIX semaphores but to no avail. Problem still exists!