# Dynamic memory allocation and multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, strtok

I have a program that uses some form of trees, hashtables and lists and finds similarities between two files. Basically, it's something like an inverted index. The program runs fine but I want to use multithreading for parallelization.

The problem that I'm facing is that the part that I want to parallelize, creates a list and does some searches at the tree that I have. This leads to incorrect results. I know that I can use mutex and lock the specific part, but this results to zero improvements in time.

So, my question is. Can I allocate memory for a specific thread? And if I can't, how can I approach this issue?

Follows the part that I want to parallelize.

```
List list;
HashTable tokenHash;
initializeList(list);
createHashTable(tokenHash);
char * token = strtok(cur_doc_str, " ");
while( token != NULL ) {
    list = searchTokenAtStructs(token, tree, hash);
    insertSearchedTokensToHashTable(tokenHash, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Edit: I'm newbie to threads and got lost but eventually through some debugging I figured out that the problem is `strtok`. It isn't thread-safe. `strtok_r` seems to does the trick.

Thank you all for your answers. They helped me to better understand threads.

Comment: You can used a single block of memory organized into array elements in a threaded environment as long as you are strict about which thread can access which element of the memory block  ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548355/threading-and-thread-safety-in-c))  But generally you will want to learn about thread concepts for same sharing of resources, eg: re-entrance, semaphores, critical sections, token sharing, mutex  etc.

Comment: Some [introductory reading](https://dev.to/quantumsheep/basics-of-multithreading-in-c-4pam).

Comment: If the tree your threads are searching is guaranteed not to change while the threads are active, then the threads can all read from it simultaneously without any problems.  As for the list, can you have each thread create its own sublist, and then at the end (after you've `pthread_join()`'d all of the threads to make sure they are no longer running) your main thread could append all the sublists together to get the final result?

Answer (score 2):

One approach, if you're allocating a lot of the same kind of object, would be to *pool* the objects. Say you have a `treeNode_t` struct. Let each thread have its own linked list of "free" `treeNode_t` objects. Instead of ever calling `free(treeNode)`, your code could put the node onto the calling thread's free list. And, before calling `malloc()`, you'd first check the free list, and take a node from there if one is available. Only call `malloc()` to get a node when the free list is empty.

---

**But first...**

Are you *sure* that the "incorrect" results that you're getting are because `malloc()` and `free()` aren't working correctly in your multi-threaded version? If that really *is* the problem, then another possibility is that you're using the wrong library. I'd be very surprised if your build tools let you write multi-threaded code without giving you a thread-safe `malloc()` and `free()`, but maybe you have to specify some compile-time or link-time option to get the thread-safe version of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can allocate memory for a specific thread. You can call `malloc` from any thread.

If you don't need to share that data across threads that's everything you need to do.

Comment: `new` is not `C`.  And regarding  _"If you don't need to share that data across threads"_ ,  OP says clearly that it needs to support parallelization in a multi-threaded environment.  Can you clear up your wording a little?

Comment: @ryyker Parallelization in threads does not imply sharing.